# How to measure voltage drop along silver foil with nanovolt precision, using Arduino's ADC?

Tags: arduino, amplifier, circuit-design, instrumentation-amplifier

For a project I am doing, it would be useful to measure voltage fluctuations in the microvolt/nanovolt area. The scenario is the following: I have a voltage divider circuit set up with R1 being a 4 Ω resistor and R2 being a 5cm pure silver foil with dimensions 5cm length and 1cm width (presumably having a resistance in the milliohms range). These R1 and R2 are connected in series using jumper wires in the breadboard.

So I am taking the Vout from this divider i.e. the drop across the silver foil (R2) (I know the jumper wire resistance will contribute to this drop as well) and then amplifying it using an opamp set to 100 gain.
The Arduino ADC gives an output, visualized with the serial monitor.

When the silver foil will be mixed with some chemicals, its electrical properties will change slightly and hence its conductivity as well. I am only interested in measuring the difference i.e. voltage drop across silver foil before the solution is mixed and after the solution is mixed (does not have to be accurate).

- Is the current method I am using valid?
- Can I measure nanovolt differences using this method?
- Is there any other more effective and reliable methods of measuring differences with nanovolt resolution?

Comment: You are trying to measure a very small DC value superimposed on a much larger one - always a pain. Instead I would use a Wheatstone bridge and a good instrumentation amplifier with a boatload of gain. Trim the bridge so that in the default condition you get 0V. As you add the chemicals, your voltage will vary from zero with changing resistance.

Comment: See this app note from Linear: [AN43 Bridge Circuits](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an43f.pdf).

Comment: @PeterK - You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: The connections on a plastic breadboard are far from perfect, so variations in them may seriously affect your readings.

Comment: You should be happy if you can measure microvolt differences, but nanovolt would be a heavy problem, especially if DC.

Answer (score 4):

The Arduino has a 10 bit ADC with 1024 levels, so the minimum change you can detect with your method is 1 part in 1024, ie. ~0.1%. In practice you need to keep within the ADC's input voltage range and above its noise floor, so the practical sensitivity will be lower (perhaps 0.2~0.5%).

However that's not your biggest problem. To *reliably* detect small changes you need very stable analog circuitry that is not affected by confounding factors such as wiring resistance, thermocouple effects and amplifier drift.

You are using a 4Ω resistor to set the current to a fixed value, presumably by connecting it to +5V. This will draw a bit over 1A so the resistor will have to dissipate more than 5W, and it will get *hot*. As a result its resistance will change, and so will the current. Supply voltage variations and changes in circuit resistance will also affect the current.

A more constant current can be created using a 3 terminal voltage regulator (eg. LM317) in [current regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM317#Current_regulator) mode. The regulator should be attached to a large heatsink to keep it cool.

When dissimilar metals are joined together and exposed to a temperature difference, a small voltage may be produced ([Seebeck effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect)). To minimize this you should try to keep the wiring and connections at a constant temperature (keep that hot resistor well away from the rest of the circuit!).

Joints may have randomly varying resistance which could introduce noise into your voltage measurement. Where practicable you should solder all joints, and use tightly screwed or bolted connections for the rest (no breadboards!). You should make a [Kelvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing) (4 wire) connection to your silver foil, so that small resistance variations in the end connections don't don't affect your readings.

DC amplifiers drift and produce noise, both of which are amplified along with the signal. You should use a 'zero-drift' or "chopper stabilized" op amp, and take the average of many readings to reduce noise.

If you need greater sensitivity then you can make a differential measurement between the foil and a reference which is adjusted to the same initial voltage. This is commonly called a [Wheatstone Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge). You can then increase amplifier gain without the signal becoming too large for the Arduino's ADC.

Answer (score 0):

Such measurements are almost always done using a bridge circuit, and ideally using AC excitation. A bridge circuit would use foil 2x as long, with one half of it covered - say painted with epoxy or wrapped in Kapton tape. Then only one half of the foil is modified chemically, and if there’s any impedance change, it will shift the balance of the bridge. The differential voltage can be amplified and synchronously detected.

If I were to start something like what you describe, with just the parts I got laying around, I’d do it like below. The 100W heat dump would be three paralleled 1200W 120V water heating coils. Their parallel resistance when cool amounts to about 4 Ohms. I also have a 1kW audio amplifier, and could dump way more than 5A at 20VACrms through the foil, but even 5A would be a good start probably.

If that yielded positive results, I’d then design and wind a custom 1kW 5kHz resonant audio transformer, with very low output impedance to match the foil, and run the experiment again at “full tilt”. The foil would be obviously getting extremely hot quickly, having 1kW dumped into it, so this would be pulsed operation only: a few ms worth of data, enough to demodulate a usable value.

The audio world is full of ultra-low-noise preamplifiers, digitizers with optical output, etc., so for the signal chain I’d use a 2-channel audio solution feeding to the PC via toslink, rather than a bespoke signal conditioner and Arduino. The parameters of the audio solution, even a cheap one, will handily beat anything you can quickly put together at component level. I happen to have some 0.6nV/sqrt(Hz) preamps, as well as a battery-powered audio digitizer, so that’s what I’d use.

Data analysis on PC would involve removing a quadratic trend from both channels, thus making them symmetric around 0, and then multiplying the signals together to perform synchronous demodulation, then taking the DC average of the result. This can all be done using common audio processing software, or just Octave. The DC average is the measure of bridge imbalance, and thus the signal you seek.

[image: Audio-friendly solution]

If I absolutely had to do this using an Arduino and other parts I got around at the lab, I’d probably start with the below, but wouldn’t expect anything great. I don’t have very low noise op-amps, but at 1kHz even this setup would provide some measurable results. A Bluetooth-connected Arduino would send the data wirelessly to the PC, since to avoid ground loops and common mode problems, the Arduino and the preamp must be operating on an isolated power supply, without connection to any grounded devices like PCs.

[image: A home brew component-level solution]